# Use terminal command in ruby code?

Tags: ruby

Is there any way to use command line commands in ruby code ?

Like : Some third party .ipa installer command inside ruby code(reinstall the app between scenarios using a 3rd party installer like ideviceinstaller).

Comment: http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html

Answer (score 1):

- **`Kernel#exec`**, that replaces your ruby process with the one you specified, as a corresponding syscall. Therefore, it ends the program even if there's more code to run. Probably not what you want. Works like: `exec("this")`
- **Backticks.** `` `this` `` will run `this` and return its stdout as a string. The same thing with different syntax: `%x(this)`
- **`Kernel#system`**: mostly same as `exec`, but **doesn't replace your Ruby process** and returns a boolean... most of the time: whether it worked successfully (`true`), it returned non-zero (`false`) or failed to run at all (`nil`); runnable as `system("this")`
- **[See these three and links to more](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands)**